# Verify that an array gets set

Tags: mockito

I'm trying to verify that my array is getting values set, but I can't figure out how to do the comparison with Mockito / Mockito Kotlin

```
class Presenter(private var repo: repo,
                private var list: List<Data> = arrayListOf()) {
   fun setData(){
       list = repo.getData()
   }
}
```

I can't figure out how to verify this happens, and not sure what the appropriate way to do it is after googling

```
@Test
fun `setData`() {

    val myList: List<Data> = mock()
    val repo: Repo = mock()
    val presenter = Presenter(repo, myList)

    val returnedList: List<Data> = listOf(Data())

    whenever(repo.getData()).thenReturn(returnedList)

    presenter.setData()

    verify ?????
}
```

I've tried having myList be a real object, and a mock object but neither works?

Things like myList.count() simply returns 0 after calling it with real or mocked() instead of the expected 1

Either verifying that the size is 1, or that it's equal to list would suffice.

Comment: You're calling a getData() method that doesn't exist, and you're not calling the setData() method that you want to test.

Comment: Sorry I rewrote the names in the middle and screwed up.  Assume all my calls are correct.  That's not the issue, I don't know how to verify once done.  I'll fix it.

Comment: The list is completely private, and isn't used or exposed anywhere, in any way. So there's no way to test that it has been modified by the method.

Comment: The list is passed into the constructor, so I have full access to it, real or mocked

Comment: You pass one list in the constructor, but the setData method replaces that list by another one. And you can't ask what the new list is, so, I repeat, there is no way to test that the list is indeed replaced by the new one.

Comment: So if that's the issue, I should be going list.clear then list.addall() and it would be the same list?

Comment: No, you simply should remove that list completely, since it isn't used anywhere. Or, if it's actually used somewhere, you should show us the relevant code, so that we can help you.

Comment: I don't think this is correct... This is example code not real code, and there should be a way to verify that it's been altered/modified regardless of it it's used anywhere else.

Comment: No, there shouldn't. The point of private is to keep things... private. You can of course use reflection to test that the list is indeed replaced, but what's the point of testing nonsensical code?

Comment: I'm just going to disagree with you here, this is testable somehow

Comment: OK. Good luck then.

Answer (score 0):

So given the initial discussion on the question, if I test with a real list and I don't set the list to the results of `repo.getData`, and instead add all the content into the list it works as expected.

I'd still be keen on way to do this by just assigning the value instead of add all however.

```
class Presenter(private var repo: repo,
                private var list: ArrayList<Data> = arrayListOf()) {
   fun setData() {
       list.clear()
       list.addAll(repo.getData())
   }
}

@Test
fun `setData`() {
    val myList: ArrayList<Data> = arrayListOf()
    val repo: Repo = mock()
    val presenter = Presenter(repo, myList)

    val returnedList: List<Data> = listOf(Data())

    whenever(repo.getData()).thenReturn(returnedList)

    presenter.setData()

    assertEquals(1, myList.count)
}
```